# Save Results As - Delimiter Issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I am trying to save results of my query to a CSV file. The first time I did this, I got a text to columns window and I chose comma as delimiter. But after that Excel automatically delimits through comma and I need to change it to TAB. What should I do? Results to Grid in SQL Server does not have the option of delimiter.

Comment: If it's not an enormous amount of data, and there's no newlines or tabs in the data, you can left click the box at the top left of the results grid to select all rows and columns (just like in excel), then right click and copy, then paste to a text file. Columns copied in this way will be pasted with tab delimiters

Comment: I have blank cells in the data and this method causes the data to move incorrectly to different columns

Comment: No, blank cells will not cause that. If you mean the column isn't aligned... it doesn't have to be. It's a CSV. You're not going to get nicely aligned columns where every value in the column has the same horizontal width. If you want that, paste it into excel instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

First, "Tools" --> "Options" --> Search "Results to text" and change output format:

[image]

Then change visualization of query, "Query" --> "Results to Text":

[image]

Then you will have results separated with tab and you can save it:

[image]

Don't forget to remove last metadata from your file or remove it using SQL Managment options:

```
(1000 rows affected)


Completion time: 2022-07-28T08:48:42.9340430+02:00
```

Don't forget to change file extension in "Save As" dialog, something like myFyle.csv

I don't know how to do this with grid, I think that it's not possible.

Comment: I tried this solution but during save as I am not able to save as CSV.

Comment: Don't forget to change file extension in "Save As" dialog, something like myFyle.csv